# Is it possible to access interface implementation method when we have access only to the interface?

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-source

I have an instance of an Interface IWindowManager that i retrieve via `WindowManagerGlobal.getWindowManagerService()`.

```
/**
 * System private interface to the window manager.
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
interface IWindowManager
{
...
}
```

I know this interface is implemented by WindowManagerService defined in `com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService`. However seam their is no way to access it, i always receive `W/System.err(10293): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService;`

but as i already have the instance, and i just want to access the method         `public Object getWindowManagerLock()` implemented in `com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService`.

```
public class WindowManagerService extends IWindowManager.Stub
        implements Watchdog.Monitor, WindowManagerPolicy.WindowManagerFuncs {

    @Override
    public Object getWindowManagerLock() {
        return mWindowMap;
    }

}
```

Is their any way for me to execute this method and retrieve the result ?

Comment: `"However seam their is no way to access it"`, what do you mean "access it"? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to run the method getWindowManagerLock() implemented in com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService

Comment: when do you get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService;`? after calling what code?

Comment: when i try to cast WindowManagerGlobal.getWindowManagerService() to WindowManagerService :( maybe i do something wrong somewhere. What i know i have WindowManagerGlobal.getWindowManagerService() that return me an interface and i want to know if it's possible to cast it to WindowManagerService object

Comment: so what is the class of `WindowManagerGlobal.getWindowManagerService()` ? did you try to `Object service = WindowManagerGlobal.getWindowManagerService(); Log.d(TAG, "service class " + service.getClass());`  ?

Comment: Thanks pskink. yes, this return me: `android.view.IWindowManager$Stub$Proxy` ... don't really know what it's mean

Comment: `service.getClass().getSuperclass());`   return me `java.lang.Object`

Comment: and `Class#getInterfaces()` ?

Comment: `service.getClass().getInterfaces()` return me `[Ljava.lang.Class;@7a3c5fc`

Comment: how long is it? whats inside?

Comment: what you mean by how long ? when i do `Log.d("log", service.getClass().getInterfaces()); ` i only receive `[Ljava.lang.Class;@7a3c5fc`

Comment: did you read `Class#getInterfaces()` javadocs?

Comment: i can't find any javadocs regarding Class#getInterfaces in the source code of android :(

Comment: i just searched everywhere, launch the android sdk manager, i can't find anything regarding <sdk_root>/docs/ :(

Comment: so install it: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager (Documentation for Android SDK)

Comment: i have it installed but their is not the option "Documentation for Android SDK" like on this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkoDD.png ... seam now the documentation can be read only online ...

Comment: yes, there is: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/sdk-manager-tools_2-0_2x.jpg

Comment: ok :) i found, it's available only under android studio ;) but their is nothing about getInterfaces() :(

Comment: no, there is complete `java.lang.Class` documentation - including `Class#getInterfaces()` method

Comment: i not sure i understand, but searching `getInterfaces()` in all the source return me only this for `java.lang.Class` "Returns an array of Class objects that match the interfaces in the implements declaration of the class represented by this Class. The order of the elements in the array is identical to the order in the original class declaration. If the class does not implement any interfaces, an empty array is returned.

This method only returns directly-implemented interfaces, and does not include interfaces implemented by superclasses or superinterfaces of any implemented interfaces."

Comment: so thats why i asked: `how long is it? whats inside? `

Comment: aaaaaaaaah ok i understand :) one min i do it now :)

Comment: ok, so their only 1 item in `getInterfaces()`, it is `java.lang.Class` and it's superclass is `java.lang.Object`

Comment: it's because i do `service.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getClass()` and  `service.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getClass().getSuperclass() ` ?

Comment: it's was not this i must do ?

Comment: `service.getClass().getInterfaces()[0]` - this is the first item, isnt it?

Comment: yes it is, and it show in log interface `android.view.IWindowManager`

Comment: so this is the class you can make your cast to - and not `WindowManagerService` what you tried

Comment: :( so no way to cast it to WindowManagerService ?

Comment: no - only to `android.view.IWindowManager`

Comment: ok, i understand :( **THANKS** pskink ! so it's seam their is no way for me to access WindowManagerService instance :(